# Determine clusters from distance information?

Tags: cluster-analysis

Consider the following example. Define, e.g., 3 clusters with 30 elements each, as follows:

```
clusters = 3;
elements = 30;
r := (2 RandomInteger[{0, 1}] - 1) RandomReal[{1, 10}]
centers = Table[r, {i, 1, clusters}, {j, 1, 3}];
clouds = Flatten[ Table[centers[[i]] + {r, r, r}/10, {i, 1, clusters}, {j, 1, elements}], 1];
```

The list `clouds` contains 90 three dimensional vectors, whose points clearly form three clusters as can be seen from the plot:

```
ListPointPlot3D[clouds]
```

> [image]

Consider then creating a matrix of distances between all the points:

```
distances =  Table[Sqrt[(clouds[[i]] - clouds[[j]]).(clouds[[i]] - clouds[[j]])], {i, 1, Length[clouds]}, {j, 1, Length[clouds]}];
```

My question is:

> Given just the 90x90 matrix `distances`, can Mathematica help us recover the number of clusters that the 90 points form, and determine the indices of the points that belong to each respective cluster?

PS:

I tried the following:

```
dist[x_, y_] := distances[[x, y]]
FindClusters[Range[clusters elements], DistanceFunction -> (dist[#1, #2] &)]
```

but this results in a lot of error messages and never finishes calculating.

Comment: `FindClusters[clouds]`?

Comment: @thorimur please, note that we used `clouds` here to generate the `distances` matrix, but in the actual question we assume that only `distances` is given and no further information is available.

Comment: Ah! I missed the crucial part, sorry. Sometimes I overlook the obvious, so I thought I'd check...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with Mathematica assuming these are numeric values being fed into a numerics-based distance function, and doing some preprocessing as a result.

I was able to force Mathematica to stop doing this by introducing an inert wrapper, which is stripped in the distance computation by `First` and again after clustering by `/. f[x_] :> x`:

```
indexclusters = Block[{f}, FindClusters[f /@ Range[clusters elements], 
    DistanceFunction -> (distances[[First @ #1, First @ #2]] &)] /. f[x_] :> x];

ListPointPlot3D[clouds[[#]] & /@ indexclusters]
```

[image: The point cloud, but colored according to cluster membership.]
(There may, of course, be more efficient ways to strip the wrapper at the necessary different stages when dealing with large data!)